# How to add or import multiple items to a file which saved in Documents Directory with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, documentsdirectory

As you can see, here is how to add a word "hello" to a `Test.txt` (saved in `Documents Directory` of an app):

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Test").appendingPathExtension("txt")

try! Data("hello".utf8).write(to: archiveURL)
```

[image: Picture1]

Suppose I have a txt or csv file (with 300 names saved one by one in line: Picture1), which is saved in iCloud Drive or somewhere. How can I add those names to the Test.txt file (saved in `Documents Directory` of an app) with one time, just the following gif shows (Picture 2). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: So the question is how to append text to an existing txt file? I mean You want to add/merge both files?

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually，I only need those named to be added to the Test.txt file.

Comment: at the end or beginning of the file? You can use FileHandle

Comment: @LeoDabus At the beginning woule be OK. Sorry，I‘m new to Swift. I haven't too much experience on File Manager of iOS…

Comment: If you want to append at the end it would be easier. At the beginning you would have to load the first txt data into memory, seek the beginning of the file, write the new text to it, then you would have to seek the end of it and write the original txt back to the file

Comment: check my answer

Comment: another option if you need to insert it at the beginning of that file would be would be to creating a new temporary file and then replacing the original one after appending both texts to it.